# Kernel of functional on dual space is weak-* closed iff it is evaluation functional

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $f \in X^{**}$. Show that $\ker f$ is weak-* closed if and only if $f = i_x$ for some $x \in X$, where $i_x\in X^{**}$ is the evaluation functional $i_x(g)\equiv g(x)$ ($g\in X^*$).

I’ve seen [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713972/show-annihilator-is-closed-subspace-of-dual-space), but in this problem the author considers the case with a set of kernels. Can I reduce my problem to this one?

Comment: Saying $ker(f)$ is $*$-weak closed is nonsense, because $ker(f)$ is not a subset of $X^*$. The notation $f=i(X)*g\mapsto g(X)$ doesn't make much sense as far as I can see. To start, try stating the problem correctly.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thank you, it was a typo, $f \in X^{**}$, I updated question

Comment: Like  pulling teeth: $f=i(X)*g\mapsto g(X)$ is still gibberish. _What does the problem actually ask_?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Updated, it should be better this way

Comment: It's still nonsense. Writing $f:i_xg\mapsto g(x)$, if it means anything, means that $f(i_xg)$ is $g(x)$. Which makes no sense. _Why not_ simply copy the problem exactly as it's written? (It looks to me like you're taking more than one sentence/formula and mashing them together. That doesn't always work - it's a bad idea, especially if you're confused about what it all means.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich unfortunately, it is exactly like my lecturer wrote this problem

Comment: I find that hard to believe. If so you should ask  him what the notation means. (Do you have a document that he wrote in front of you, or are you concluding that that's what he wrote because that's what your notes look like? _Was_ $f=i(X)*g\mapsto g(X)$ _also_ exactly what he wrote?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, I have. It is not English, but this notation is in the bottom of photo.
https://imgur.com/JABdDxV

Comment: No. The photo does not say $f:i_xg\mapsto g(x)$. It says $f=i(x)g\mapsto g(x)$. Not that that makes any sense either, but for heaven's sake, when you can't even be bothered to transcribe the problem correctly it's really hard to see why you'd expect someone to try to _first_ figure out what you mean and _then_ try to solve it for you!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich at the beginning I wrote it exactly as it was on photo. When you said, that it is incorrect, I tried to fix it as I can

Comment: No you didn't. Your first version included $i(X)$ - that's one difference I remember... In any case, you need to ask the guy what the notation means.

Comment: Lucky you, I figured out a coherent statement of the problem: "Suppose $f\in X^{**}$. Show that $ker(f)$ is $*$-weak closed if and only if $f=i(x)$ for some $x\in X$. Here $i:X\to X^{**}$ is the canonical embedding; in other words $i(x)$ is the functional $g\mapsto g(x)$ ($g\in X^*$)."

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thank you very much, you did a great job. But I still have no thoughts. Could you suggest some ideas, please?

Comment: I've spent way too much time on this already. Hint: One direction is trivial, from the _definition_ of the weak-* topology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $\phi\in X^{**}$ and that $\phi=i_x$ for some $x\in X$ (I prefer to reserve the notation $f$ for elements of $X^*$). Since the weak-star topology on $X^*$ is, by definition, the weakest topology that renders all $\{i_y\mid y\in X\}$ continuous, it follows, in particular, that $\phi$ is weak-star continuous and its kernel is weak-star closed.

Conversely, suppose that $\ker\phi$ is weak-star closed. If $\phi$ identically vanishes, then $\phi=i_0$, so assume that there exists some $f\in X^*$ such that $\phi(f)\neq 0$. Therefore, $f\in X^*\setminus\ker\phi$. Now, since $X^*\setminus\ker\phi$ is open in the weak-star topology, the way the weak-star topology is generated guarantees the existence of some $\varepsilon>0$, $n\in\mathbb N$, and $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in X$ such that $$f\in\bigcap_{j=1}^n\left\{g\in X^*\mid|i_{x_j}(g)-i_{x_j}(f)|<\varepsilon\right\}\subseteq X^*\setminus\ker\phi.$$
Let the intersection appearing in the formula above be denoted as $U$. I now claim that $$\bigcap_{j=1}^n\ker i_{x_j}\subseteq\ker\phi.\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ Indeed, if $g\in X^*$ is such that $g(x_1)=\cdots=g(x_n)=0$, then $f+\mu g\in U\subseteq X^*\setminus\ker\phi$ for all $\mu\in\mathbb F$ (where $\mathbb F\in\{\mathbb R,\mathbb C\}$ is the underlying field). This implies that $\phi(f+\mu g)=\phi(f)+\mu\phi(g)\neq 0$ for any $\mu\in\mathbb F$, which is only possible if $\phi(g)=0$; otherwise, one could take $\mu=-\phi(f)/\phi(g)$. Therefore, $g\in\ker\phi$, as claimed.

Finally, $(\clubsuit)$ implies that $\phi\in\operatorname{span}\{i_{x_1},\ldots,i_{x_n}\}$. To see this, define $\Xi:X^*\to\mathbb F^n$ as $$\Xi(g)\equiv(i_{x_1}(g),\ldots,i_{x_n}(g))\quad\text{for each $g\in X^*$.}$$ Note that if some $g,h\in X^*$ satisfy $$(i_{x_1}(g),\ldots,i_{x_n}(g))=(i_{x_1}(h),\ldots,i_{x_n}(h)),$$ then $i_{x_j}(g-h)=0$ for all $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, so that $(\clubsuit)$ implies that $\phi(g)=\phi(h)$. Therefore, the function $\Psi:\Xi(X^*)\to\mathbb F$, defined as $$\Psi(i_{x_1}(g),\ldots,i_{x_n}(g))\equiv\phi(g)\quad\text{for $g\in X^*$},$$ is well-defined. It is easy to check that it is also a linear function mapping from $\Xi(X^*)$ (which is a linear subspace of $\mathbb F^n$) to $\mathbb F$, so that it can be extended to a linear function mapping from $\mathbb F^n$ to $\mathbb F$ (details provided below). This implies that there exist $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb F$ such that, for each $g\in X^*$, $$\phi(g)=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j i_{x_j}(g)=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_ jg(x_j)=g\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_ jx_j\right).$$ Hence, $\phi=i_{\lambda_1x_1+\cdots+\lambda_nx_n}$, which completes the proof.

---

Let me explain how to extend $\Psi:\Xi(X^*)\to\mathbb F$ to a linear function mapping from $\mathbb F^n$ to $\mathbb F$ and where the coefficients $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ come from. Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}\subseteq\Xi(X^*)$ be a basis for the subspace $\Xi(X^*)$, where $m\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. (The case in which $\Xi(X^*)=\{(0,\ldots,0)\}$ is pretty trivial.) [It is possible to extend it](https://planetmath.org/everyvectorspacehasabasis) to a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_m,e_{m+1},\ldots,e_n\}\subseteq\mathbb F^n$ of $\mathbb F^n$. Each $z\in\mathbb F^n$ has a unique representation $$z=\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_j^ze_j\quad\text{for some $\alpha_1^z,\ldots,\alpha_n^z\in\mathbb F$}.$$ For each $z\in\mathbb F^n$, define $$\Theta(z)\equiv\sum_{j=1}^m\alpha_j^z\Psi(e_j).$$ It is not difficult to check that $\Theta:\mathbb F^n\to\mathbb F$ is linear and satisfies $\Theta(z)=\Psi(z)$ for $z\in\Xi(X^*)$. The coefficients $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ can now be defined as
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1\equiv&\;\Theta(1,0,\ldots,0,0),\\
\lambda_2\equiv&\;\Theta(0,1,\ldots,0,0),\\
\vdots&\;\\
\lambda_{n-1}\equiv&\;\Theta(0,0,\ldots,1,0),\\
\lambda_n\equiv&\;\Theta(0,0,\ldots,0,1).
\end{align*}
This way, one has, for each $g\in X^*$,
\begin{align*}
\phi(g)=&\;\Psi(i_{x_1}(g),i_{x_2}(g),\ldots,i_{x_{n-1}}(g),i_{x_n}(g))=\Theta(i_{x_{1}}(g),i_{x_2}(g),\ldots,i_{x_{n-1}}(g),i_{x_n}(g))\\
=&\;\Theta\big(i_{x_{1\phantom{-n}}}(g)\times(1,0,\ldots,0,0)+i_{x_2}(g)\times(0,1,\ldots,0,0)+\cdots+\\
&\;\phantom{\Theta\big(}i_{x_{n-1}}(g)\times(0,0,\ldots,1,0)+i_{x_n}(g)\times(0,0,\ldots,0,1)\big)\\
=&\;i_{x_{1\phantom{-n}}}(g)\times\Theta(1,0,\ldots,0,0)+i_{x_2}(g)\times\Theta(0,1,\ldots,0,0)+\cdots+\\
&\;i_{x_{n-1}}(g)\times\Theta(0,0,\ldots,1,0)+i_{x_{n}}(g)\times\Theta(0,0,\ldots,0,1)\\
=&\;\sum_{j=1}^n i_{x_j}(g)\times\lambda_j.
\end{align*}

Comment: You probably saw my Comment on another post of yours (about broken links to PlanetMath), so now I'll just link [every vector space has a basis](https://planetmath.org/everyvectorspacehasabasis) for your perusal. The PDF to HTML conversion they did is somewhat clunky, so you might prefer to link a good proof from another website.

Comment: I replaced the PlanetMath link.  Of course you can rollback my edit if you wish.