# Closed subspace of finite codimension

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, weak-topology

When will a closed subspace of finite codimension in a Banach space is weak* closed? Is it always true? Is it true atelast in $B(\mathcal H)$ where $\mathcal H$ is Hilbert space.

Comment: Take $X$ to be non-reflexive and an element $f$ of $X^{**}$ that isn't in $X$. The kernel of $f$ has co-dimension $1$ but is not weak* closed. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2576053/kernel-of-functional-on-dual-space-is-weak-closed-iff-it-is-evaluation-functio).

Comment: Is there some sufficient condition which will imply weak* closed?